# comet callback-polling and jetty-cometd implementation

Tags: servlets, jetty, cometd, get-method

I am using the cometd implementation that comes with the jetty server. I'd like to use the callback-polling transport, but when I try to connect to the comet server from javascript (note that the html page is in another web-server), jetty complains that the servlet does not supports the GET method. Is this an error/bug/whatever of the jetty implementation or I am missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, seems that GET method wasn't supported in older versions of cometd-jetty implementation. Recent (>= 6.1.19, maybe even before) does support it.